# sorting a list of objects by two properties

Tags: list, vb.net, sorting, autodesk-inventor

So I have a list of objects which have a point 2d as a property on them. Up until now I've been using this function to sort the list by the X values going left to right

```
BalloonList.Sort(Function(Balloon1, Balloon2) Balloon1.Leader.AllNodes(2).Position.X.CompareTo(Balloon2.Leader.AllNodes(2).Position.X))
```

However, I now need a conditional sort for when two of these points have the same (Ideally within a small range) it sorts them by the Y Value from top to bottom. What's the best method to do this?

For more context, I am Ballooning an assembly in Autodesk inventor using VB.net

```
BalloonList.Sort(Function(Balloon1, Balloon2) Balloon1.Leader.AllNodes(2).Position.X.CompareTo(Balloon2.Leader.AllNodes(2).Position.X))
```

Comment: If you have access to the `Position` class, you could implement `IComparable`